# accessing outlook server in java

Tags: java, email

[image]

[image]

I am trying to access my outlook account .. which results in the following error..

any help ??,

Comment: Please copy the text instead of posting a (JPEG!) screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a POP3 or IMAP provider.  Those are for reading.  SMTP is for sending.